# Conditional operator syntax

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have been reading C++ Primer for a whole day and stuck at this piece of code which I accidentally typed out:

```
int max = 5, min = 4;
max = (max > min) ? max : min;
```

It becomes so wired for me to think of it as `max = max;`.

According to my understanding the right side `max` becomes a *rvalue* so it is merely a value `5`. I'm not sure at all...

Anyone please explain it to me in plain words what's this syntax is?

As a newbie I think I'm not able to understand too complex answers.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `max` and `min` are merely variables. You could as well just change their names or exchange their values if you so wish.

Comment: It's kind of odd code, I would write `if (min > max) max = min;`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually I have been self-learning C++ for around 3 weeks, everyday started from 7 am to 11pm, only C++...LOL..I am going to take a C++ course with CS students next summer vacation. That's why I have to learn more during this holiday.

Comment: Come back after six months :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit !!!:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
max = (max > min) ? max : min;
```

could be decomposed to:

```
if (max > min) {
    max = max;
} else {
    max = min;
}
```

Thus, what is happens is `max` is compared to `min` and whichever is *greater than* the other gets assigned to `max`. The last operation, in the case where `max` is greater than `min`, is called self assignment:

```
max = max;
```

which is a perfectly legal operation, with accordance with the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, "is called self assignment" clearly explained my question. I will accept your answer later.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strange about the expression

```
max = max;
```

because there is no requirement the right hand side *must* be an rvalue, it just happens to be an rvalue often.

For example this is a typical copy from one lvalue to another

```
int x = 5;
int y;
y = x;
```

In this case `x` is not an rvalue, yet it appears on the right hand side. It is simply used to copy-assign to `y`.

So in your ternary expression either `max = max` or `max = min` are the two assignments that can possibly occur, and both are assignments using lvalues.

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks for the effort! I'm so sorry but I think I understand his answer better. Sorry!